# How to know if an Image is given an illegal source?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have created a list of Image object. Every Image's onload function is the same:

```
function tracker() {
    ++loadedImage;
    if (loadedImage === total) ..
}

images[i].src = urls[i];
```

This function tries to see if all the images are loaded, if so, call another function. However, several sources are illegal (maybe not existing) so the onload function will never be called for those images. I want to increment loadedImage even if the object is given an illegal source. However can I know if an Image is given an illegal source?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve (and when), [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) might be an alternative. It fires, when the document *and* all resources are loaded

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/a/b"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x50"/>
```

```js
window.onload = function(evt) {
    console.log('window.onload');
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i) {
    var img = imgs[i];
    img.onload = function(evt) {
        console.log('src=' + this.src + ', ready');
    }
    img.onerror = function(evt) {
        console.log('src=' + this.src + ', error');
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JEtwL/)

Answer (score 3):

Images also have an `error` event. You can hook it too and count failed loads from here.

If you plan to support IE8-, be aware that `load` events won't fire if the image happens to be already present in the browser's cache.